# ¿Alguien sabe por qué me pone else without if?

Tags: java

Se trata de una empresa en la que se pregunta el nombre del trabajador, su antigüedad y su clave. dependiendo de la clave y de su antigüedad le corresponderán distintos días de vacaciones.

Lo que me pasa es que cuando ejecuto el programa por alguna razón que desconozco me sale fallo en lo del else y en el if.

Me gustaría saber si por favor alguien me podría ayudar a solucionar este problema.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SistemaClavesTrabajadores2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre = "";
        int clave = 0, antiguedad = 0;

        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("*Bienvenido al sistema de vacaciones de CocaCola Company*");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("¿Cuál es su nombre?: ");
        nombre = entrada.next.Line();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("¿Cuánto tiempo lleva trabajando en esta empresa?: ");
        antiguedad = entrada.next.Int();
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("¿Cuál es la clave del trabajador?: ");
        clave = entrada.next.Int();
        System.out.println("");

        if (clave == 1) {

            if (antiguedad == 1) {
                System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 6 dias de vacaciones");
                else if (antniguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6) {
                    System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 14 dias de vacaciones");
                    else if (antniguedad >= 7) {
                        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 20 dias de vacaciones");

                        else if (clave == 2) {

                            if (antiguedad == 1) {
                                System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 7 dias de vacaciones");
                                else if (antniguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6) {
                                    System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 15 dias de vacaciones");
                                    else if (antniguedad >= 7) {
                                        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 22 dias de vacaciones");

                                        else if (clave == 3) {

                                            if (antiguedad == 1) {
                                                System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 10 dias de vacaciones");
                                                else if (antniguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6) {
                                                    System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 20 dias de vacaciones");
                                                    else if (antniguedad >= 7) {
                                                        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 30 dias de vacaciones");

                                                        else {
                                                            System.out.println("La clave que ha elegido no existe");
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para que el código se vea bien, puedes copiarlo tal cual de tu IDE, seleccionarlo todo y pulsar Ctrl + K. De ese modo la anidación se verá correctamente

Comment: Por otro lado podrías cerrar cada condición, poniendo una llave `}` **antes** de cada `else`

Comment: Si, tienes un problema serio de anidamiento...  asegurate que cada bloque se abra y se cierre correctamente

Comment: te convendría usar un switch

Comment: te sugiero indentar tu codigo para empezar, asi te sera mas facil ver por que tu error indica que hay un else que no esta asociado a ningun if

Answer (score 0):

El error significa que antes de un `else` debería haber un `if` o un `else if`. Y antes del primer `else if` un `if`.

De modo que esto es válido:

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else if (b) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Y esto no:

```
else {
    ...
}
```

Ni esto, que es similar a tu código:

```
if (a) {
    ...
    else if (b) {
        ...
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Creo que te estás confundiendo sobre cómo concatenar los condicionales ya que parecen faltar o sobrar llaves.

Deduzco por las condiciones que lo que quisiste hacer en realidad es esto:

```
if (clave == 1) {

    if (antiguedad == 1)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 6 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 14 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 7)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 20 dias de vacaciones");
        
} else if (clave == 2) {

    if (antiguedad == 1)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 7 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 15 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 7)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 22 dias de vacaciones");
        
} else if (clave == 3) {

    if (antiguedad == 1)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 10 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 20 dias de vacaciones");
    else if (antiguedad >= 7)
        System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + "tiene derecho a 30 dias de vacaciones");

} else {
    System.out.println("La clave que ha elegido no existe");
}
```

Ahora no se ve tan caótico.

Nota que a los condicionales de más adentro no les puse llaves. Porque si bloque contiene instrucción una sola instrucción se pueden omitir.

---

Dado que el mensaje y las condiciones son las mismas se me ocurre que puedes simplificar más el código mediante un arreglo, así:

```
static int dias[][] = {
    { 6, 14, 20 },
    { 7, 15, 22 },
    { 10, 20, 30 }
};

static void imprimirMensaje(String nombre, int dias){
    System.out.println("El trabajador " + nombre + " tiene derecho a " + dias + " dias de vacaciones");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int antiguedad = 1;
    int clave = 1;
    String nombre = "F";
    if (clave < 0 || clave > 2){
        System.out.println("Clave incorrecta ");
        return;
    }

    if (antiguedad == 1)
        imprimirMensaje(nombre, dias[clave][0]);
    else if (antiguedad >= 2 && antiguedad <= 6)
        imprimirMensaje(nombre, dias[clave][1]);
    else if (antiguedad >= 7)
        imprimirMensaje(nombre, dias[clave][2]);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##lVKxbsIwEN3zFacMiLRplKQtDAGWqt2YGFGGI3ap08RGjhOpAr6dHiGAg1SpeLLeu7v37tk5NviUs@/DQZQbpQ3kBAS1EUXwkDjOpl4VIoOswKqCOQoJW8cBOpVBQ4SQBpjAapkuU5gSCd3ZwsiH6MWHOIS9b8Fjgl8JjvtwFB5LfXim8hbeJz2hRgkGZFGLUug5lxXmfLgwWsg1SFWuNPcvZryrjcVPZXgZqNoE1CpNIYfuewFG4wpzZEqDC4/dALq4YASXHBjXPPtSgC19nNmS7YVxaDDDTCjJK9dLTm5PZru4bM8lhdYZpYhQr217R8cojVjXnCGjAKOkx1HuDe/DvZ2Jcj9cq@cThqeeCYSw23UDZhBbon/l8tbWCpkpTdsb2t1Lek2am1rLK9YtfRa2FyHLXq/39unOb9Z@ntZlugxTS5AXFb8dO5tCDIOBHdlkCqP7laJ/KI3vHxunl@@wPxx@AQ).